# How to start with shell script with .info file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

One of my friend has started learning shell script and come through one small assignment, but he is not getting any idea how to and from where to start.

```
Problem statement is:

a. Create a file 'user_UserID.info' file under /tmp. Populate the file 'user_UserID.info' with the following data:
Username,Password,PrimaryGroup,Comment,HomeDir

b. Create a Shell script to add user accounts and set the password for the users listed in 'user_UserID.info' file. All other 
dependent activities like group creation, directory creation etc. also should be done through this script.

c. Display the content of /home directory on console. Redirect the newly created 3 user’s information to userdetails_UserID.txt
```

Here, how to create .info file and what is the purpose of it?

Please suggest. Any suggestions or good resource can be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple script , you can found million scripts like this on the internet , only search .

```
#!/bin/bash 

while read line
do
                USERNAME=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')
                PASSWORD=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}')
                PRIMARY_GROUP=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $3}')
                COMMENT=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $4}')
                HOME_DIR=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $5}') 

                groupadd $PRIMARY_GROUP
                useradd -mc $COMMENT -s /bin/bash -d $HOME_DIR $USERNAME -g $PRIMARY_GROUP
                yes "$PASSWORD" | passwd $USERNAME
done < ./user_UserID.info
```

Comment: thank you. Can you share some reference link get more understanding about shell scripting.

Comment: @User_1191 confirm answer if fixed your problem , Thank you .